# NoSuchMethodError exception in production

Tags: java, apache-commons-lang3

I am getting the following exception in production ( Tomcat server ) but not when i run unit tests.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isAllBlank([Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Z
```

I am not quite sure why this would happen in production but not with unit tests.
I can clearly see that commons-lang3 is included in the dependency so what am i missing ?

This is the maven tree :

```
--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ APPC ---
     com.spectrags.APPC:APPC:war:1.17.1-SNAPSHOT
     +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
     |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
     +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:test (scope not updated to compile)
     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
     +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
     |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
     +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
     |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.0:compile
     |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
     +- org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:5.0.0.Final:compile
     |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
     |  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.0.Final:compile
     |     +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |     +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |     +- (dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |     +- (org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |     +- (org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |     +- (org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |     \- (org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:5.0.0.Final:compile
     |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  \- (org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.10.RELEASE:compile
     |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.10.RELEASE:compile
     |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.10.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.10.RELEASE:compile
     |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.10.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.18.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.1:compile
     |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.6)
     +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile
     |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
     +- org.springframework.flex:spring-flex-core:jar:1.6.0.RC1:compile
     |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
     |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
     |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
     |  |  \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.10)
     |  +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:3.1:compile
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  +- com.adobe.blazeds:blazeds-core:jar:4.0.0.14931:compile
     |  +- com.adobe.blazeds:blazeds-common:jar:4.0.0.14931:compile
     |  +- com.adobe.blazeds:blazeds-proxy:jar:4.0.0.14931:compile
     |  \- com.adobe.blazeds:blazeds-remoting:jar:4.0.0.14931:compile
     +- org.apache.flex.blazeds:flex-messaging-core:jar:4.7.2:compile
     |  \- org.apache.flex.blazeds:flex-messaging-common:jar:4.7.2:compile
     |     \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.6.0:compile
     |        \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.4.01)
     +- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:jar:1.6.2.RELEASE:compile
     |  +- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:3.6.3:compile
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  +- (org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.5.RELEASE)
     |  +- com.rabbitmq:http-client:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
     |  |  +- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.5.2)
     |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.5.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.8.2)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  +- (org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:jar:1.6.2.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     +- org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:jar:1.6.2.RELEASE:compile
     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:jar:5.7.0:compile
     |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.7)
     |  +- (org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.apache.activemq:kahadb:jar:5.7.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- org.apache.activemq.protobuf:activemq-protobuf:jar:1.1:compile
     |  +- org.fusesource.mqtt-client:mqtt-client:jar:1.3:compile
     |  |  +- org.fusesource.hawtdispatch:hawtdispatch-transport:jar:1.11:compile
     |  |  |  \- org.fusesource.hawtdispatch:hawtdispatch:jar:1.11:compile
     |  |  \- org.fusesource.hawtbuf:hawtbuf:jar:1.9:compile
     |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1:compile
     |  \- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.9.0:compile
     +- org.apache.activemq:kahadb:jar:5.7.0:compile
     |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.7)
     +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.8.1:compile
     +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
     +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided (scope not updated to compile)
     +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
     +- taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2:compile
     +- javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar:2.2.1:provided
     +- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:2.2.4:provided
     +- org.glassfish.web:javax.el:jar:2.2.4:provided
     |  \- (javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:2.2.4:provided - omitted for duplicate)
     +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
     +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.0.Final:compile
     |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
     |  +- (org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.22.0-GA)
     |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
     |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.2.2.Final:compile
     |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
     |  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.4.01)
     |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.0.Final:compile
     |     \- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:5.0.0.Final:test
     |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:test - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.0.Final:test - omitted for duplicate)
     |  \- (com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.2.1:test - omitted for conflict with 0.9.5.2)
     +- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.5.2:test
     |  \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.11:test
     +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
     +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
     |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.3.0.Final)
     |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
     +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.22.0-GA:compile
     +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
     +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
     |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
     |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
     +- org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:jar:2.1.1:compile
     |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.4.2:compile
     |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
     +- com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar:6.3.6.jre7-preview:compile
     +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
     +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
     +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
     +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
     +- org.mvel:mvel2:jar:2.3.1.Final:compile
     +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3:compile
     +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:jar:2.2.0:test
     |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
     |  |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
     |  |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
     |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
     |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.16:test - omitted for conflict with 1.7.7)
     |  +- (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
     |  |  \- (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test - omitted for duplicate)
     |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.16:test - omitted for conflict with 1.7.7)
     +- com.aspose:aspose-cells:jar:7.3.5:compile
     +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
     +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:compile
     |  +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
     |  \- (org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.5.1:compile
     |  +- (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.9.3)
     |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:compile
     |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
     |  \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.54:compile
     +- org.apache.commons:commons-vfs2:jar:2.1:compile
     |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
     |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4:compile
     |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
     |  \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.10)
     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.2:compile
     |  \- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:2.0.2:compile
     |  +- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:2.0.2:compile
     |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
     |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
     +- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-tools:jar:2.0.2:compile
     |  \- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-debugger:jar:2.0.2:compile
     |     \- (org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:2.0.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- org.apache.pdfbox:xmpbox:jar:2.0.2:compile
     |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
     +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:2.0.2-beta:test
     +- net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:jar:9.7.0-8:test (scope not updated to compile)
     +- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.5:compile
     +- org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc:jar:1.1.3.RELEASE:compile
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:runtime - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |  \- org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-core:jar:1.1.3.RELEASE:compile
     |     +- (javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |     +- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     |     \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.6.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.5.1)
     +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.4.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.3.14.RELEASE)
     +- org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-asciidoctor:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
     +- APPCLib:APPCLib:jar:1.17.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
     |  +- org.springframework:spring-websocket:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile
     |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.3.14.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- com.sun.xsom:xsom:jar:20100725:compile
     |  |  \- (relaxngDatatype:relaxngDatatype:jar:20020414:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (com.caucho:hessian:jar:4.0.38:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (javax.xml:jaxp-api:jar:1.4.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
     |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.7)
     |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.6.2:compile
     |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.7)
     |  |  \- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.6.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- com.lmax:disruptor:jar:3.3.5:compile
     |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.6.2:compile
     |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:jar:2.6.2:compile
     |  |  +- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.6.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  |  \- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.6.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:jar:2.6.2:runtime
     |  |  +- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.6.2:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
     |  |  \- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.6.2:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.6.2:compile
     |  |  \- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.6.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jcl:jar:2.6.2:compile
     |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
     |  |  \- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.6.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.6.2:compile
     |  |  \- (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.6.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:jar:4.5:compile
     |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.1)
     |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.2:compile
     |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.2:compile
     |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
     |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5:jar:2.8.2:compile
     |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
     |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.55:compile
     |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
     |  |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.2)
     |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
     |  +- javax.mail:javax.mail-api:jar:1.5.6:compile
     |  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.6:compile
     |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
     +- SpectraML2Word:SpectraML2Word:jar:1.17.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
     |  +- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.6)
     |  +- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-matchers:jar:2.3.0:compile
     |  |  +- (org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.3.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  |  \- (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  \- (org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     +- WordToSpectraML:WordToSpectraML:jar:1.17.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
     |  +- (junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (com.aspose:aspose-words:jar:13.12.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.8.1)
     |  +- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.6)
     |  +- (org.jdom:jdom2:jar:2.0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:jar:9.7.0-18:compile - omitted for conflict with 9.7.0-8)
     |  +- (org.xmlunit:xmlunit-matchers:jar:2.3.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.3.0:compile
     +- BFO:BFO:jar:1.17.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
     |  +- bfo:bfopdf:jar:1.0:compile
     |  +- bfo:bfopdf-licence:jar:1.0:compile
     |  +- bfo:bfograph-licence:jar:1.0:compile
     |  +- bfo:bfograph-signed:jar:1.0:compile
     |  +- (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.8.1)
     |  +- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.6)
     |  +- (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.jdom:jdom2:jar:2.0.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:jar:9.7.0-18:compile - omitted for conflict with 9.7.0-8)
     |  +- (org.xmlunit:xmlunit-matchers:jar:2.3.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  +- (org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.3.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
     |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
     +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:7.0.52:test
     |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:7.0.52:test
     \- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
        \- (junit:junit:jar:4.10:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.12)
```

i have commons-lang and commons-lang3 included but it shouldn't matter since the package name are different

Comment: You have both `commons-lang:jar:2.4` and `commons-lang3:jar:3.8.1`, try removing the `commons-lang:jar:2.4`. Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485563/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-commons-lang-stringutils-isblankljava-l)

Comment: The problem is that commons-lang2.4 is a dependency of the library velocity so I am not sure it can be excluded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have commons-lang version 3.5 included twice and commons-lang3 version 3.8.x once; the method you want is included from version 3.6 onwards. See "since" in [the javadocs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isAllBlank-java.lang.CharSequence...-).

Given this, I can't help but think there's a difference between your development and production environments - you may be missing commongs-lang3 version 3.8.x in production.